# Salary scales in Germany and experience outside

Tags: germany, salary

How is the work experience outside Germany counted in public salary decisions? What if someone got their PhD outside Germany, for instance?

Some context for my own case:

I am hired as a scientist at a public research institute. I did not know much about how these salary scales work, and I received a letter from HR telling me that only my previous postdoc in Germany (which was a stipend contract and I wasn't even paid by Germany) was considered for the decision, so it is basically 1 year. It's E-14 level 2.

I did my studies in another country where PhD positions are mostly not paid so people work in industry. I have more than 10 years of experience, all in relevant roles to my current research topic, and I also have experience in team management and third party funding. I am pretty sure the hiring decision was highly affected by this experience.

I am not even sure if the PI/head of department was involved or they should have been involved in the decision, but if the decision is made based on my experience, salary should be decided based on my experience, too.

I don't care much about my current salary, but this decision will affect the rest of my career in Germany, if I will have one. So this is bugging me very much, and I need some information on how this works here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These decisions have a large degree of randomness to them. That is because they are made by administrative staff who may or may not have adequate understanding of your individual case, and what should count as relevant experience.

It is generally possible that you can influence the decision by making a strong case why your previous experience is relevant. They may or may not understand your arguments (or pretend they don't). Of course, such a case should be made before you sign the job contract.

It is also generally possible that the hiring PI and/or department head can influence the decision. The institutional setup may or may not be such that the PI or department head has formal influence. It's also possible that the administrative staff is more willing to listen to them, due to their perceived status. If the administrators don't listen to your arguments, asking the PI to make a case for you is a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: As a follow up, do you think it is possible to negotiate this in my next job? Because it seems that for my current job it's too late to negotiate. The contract itself does not have this stufe info, but in emails and the letter they gave they told me it was going to be stufe 2. Until I got the letter, I thought they considered my other experience as well, and now I heard that once you are in the system, you cannot change it before completing the duration for that level, even if you change jobs. And my experience with HR here has not been the best.

Comment: @groove: I am pretty sure that it’s nonsense that you cannot change the level once you are in the system. For example, if HR made a blatant mistake, they have to retroactively amend it. Of course, it’s more difficult. Since you already started the position (IIUC), you have less leverage and somebody somewhere has to acknowledge that they made a mistake.

Comment: @groove Possible yes - in the ideal scenario, you have an HR person who agrees to your assessment, or a PI who really wants to hire you and can influence the HR person.

Comment: @groove If you plan to become professor in Germany, that's a totally different game anyways, salary-wise. It's not even the same broader category of employment, as you will be a "Beamter" instead of "Arbeitnehmer im öffentlichen Dienst".

Comment: @lighthousekeeper That's the current plan but it seems very hard to accomplish, so I might stay in Germany as a researcher or somewhere else as a professor or a researcher. I just want to learn if I ruined my possible career in Germany since I didn't try to negotiate. I did it with another institute in another country, and I've chosen this one, but how HR treated me in other things fired up such questions in my mind and I decided to go for it and take the risk of pissing them off and get fired. Not ideal but at least better for mental relaxation.

Comment: @groove: *I just want to learn if I ruined my possible career in Germany since I didn't try to negotiate.* – You didn’t ruin much. If you stay at this position for fourteen years, we are talking about a difference of 37 k€ gross salary here (while you earn about 1 M€ in total). And before that happens, you are very likely to get a different position, be it as a professor or something else, which will likely obviate any difference.

Comment: @groove: *I decided to go for it and take the risk of pissing them off and get fired.* – Firing somebody from public service in Germany is very difficult. You might get fired within probation time if your supervisor is really unhappy with you, but usually academic employments end if your contract doesn’t get extended. Getting fired for arguing (politely) with HR would be totally outlandish. It’s the kind of situation that would actually get somebody fired from public service, namely the HR people responsible for this.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: I agree with almost everything in [your last comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/201933/salary-scales-in-germany-and-experience-outside#comment544464_201934), except for the very last sentence. In my experience, *especially* the HR people in the German public sector NEVER get fired, and especially not for obstructing employees' requests, or dragging their feet for months or years.

Comment: I was somewhat surprised about your statement that "[your pay grade/job grading -- what BAT class you are in] have a large degree of randomness". In my admittedly limited experience it is really hard for German public institutions to deviate from the formal criteria for your pay grade (most importantly your education and official job description). This has particular effects in IT, where experience and skill matters much more than formal education: Because the institutions (university, MPG etc.) cannot offer a competitive salary, they can only hire second class personnel or enthusiasts.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica For the first half: There is no objective way of assessing whether previous experiences are indeed relevant, since former experiences are generally made in different contexts than the job in question. Hence there is always a certain degree of subjectivity and hence randomness. For the second half: I agree to your assessment; however, to which degree the underlying mindset of this assessment is manifest in bureaucratic staff in German universities is, again, a matter of randomness.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper It is not so much a mindset as a procedural constraint. Consider  a professor trying to hire an AI expert. They find one, dream candidate, left high-paying job at google because they found love in Berlin. Professor pesters the HR to offer a competitive salary. Standard procedure is "No degree (because they left Stanford to found a startup that got bought by google), no team -> one step above cleaning lady". It is hard to deviate from that. The *Frauenbeauftragte* is involved, the university is generally not even offering permanent positions, *Betriebsrat* vetoes. Etc.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica For the example in this question, there doesn't seem to be procedural constraint such as a missing degree.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper That was an example. Apparently, HR has a list of items to consider when grading a job (applicant) , and some of the qualification of the OP falls through the roster, whatever it is. (Sure, the assessment of work experience may be more open to "randomness" than documented degrees, but still, they probably work down a list and tick check boxes -- or not.)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Yes, bureaucrats work with lists of check boxes. My point is that many (if not most) check boxes have some degree of subjectivity/randomness to them, especially those related to work experiences.

Answer (score 8):

First, it is not necessarily true that your experience is relevant - it must be relevant to a job in paygrade E14, and not just in some vague way to your job. There is lots of room for interpretation. The only thing which is definitely relevant is another job in the same paygrade - so if your previous experience way, say, as a PhD student, this might with good reason not be counted towards E14-experience. Note that there are clear definitions what E14 involves as a minimum (AFAIR, E13 requires an academic degree > bachelor, and E14 adds responsibility for other people to it (as a team leader etc.). For instance, PhD students would never get E14, and most places also hire postdocs only on E13.)

Now, the PI has generally some say - how much depends on the institution, but it is certainly a good idea to ask them. For sure, they would have to write some text why other experience is counted, and without such a text, it is almost certain that the administration will not upgrade you, so you will have to rely on his support and them writing such an explanation.

Comment: So experience in industry and/or in other countries doesn't count? Because I led teams of master's and phd studens in industry, not their thesis work, but we did projects on topics relevant to my current research, for instance. And I got research grants on top of that. If that experience influenced the decision to hire me, it should influence the salary too to be fair, shouldn't it? And today I also learned that experience as a PhD student in Germany counted as experience in E14, so a fresh PhD graduate working as a postdoc is making more money than me.

Comment: *"And today I also learned that experience as a PhD student in Germany counted as experience in E14"*: That depends on the place, and I would say it is really stretching the rules. If it is in the same place where you are, you might have a good argument. But again, get the support from your PI - if they bend the rules, the administration will have to add some explanation to their files, and they are not the ones who can judge the relevance of your experience and write this text.

Comment: I know PhD students that were E14 and lead other, less experienced PhD students. Never say never.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, the relevant rule here is [§ 16(2) Bund](https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/downloads/DE/veroeffentlichungen/themen/oeffentlicher-dienst/tarifvertraege/tvoed.pdf?__blob=publicationFile&v=8) or a similar rule of a similar tariff contract (translation mine):

> ¹Bei Einstellung werden die Beschäftigten der Stufe 1 zugeordnet, sofern keine einschlägige Berufserfahrung vorliegt. ²Verfügt die/der Beschäftigte über eine einschlägige Berufserfahrung von mindestens einem Jahr, erfolgt die Einstel­lung in die Stufe 2; verfügt sie/er über eine einschlägige Berufserfahrung von mindestens drei Jahren, erfolgt bei Einstellung in der Regel eine Zuordnung zur Stufe 3. ³Unabhängig davon kann der Arbeitgeber bei Neueinstellungen zur De­ckung des Personalbedarfs Zeiten einer vorherigen beruflichen Tätigkeit ganz oder teilweise für die Stufenzuordnung berücksichtigen, wenn diese Tätigkeit für die vorgesehene Tätigkeit förderlich ist.
>
> ---
>
> ¹On hiring, an employee is assigned Level 1 unless they have relevant work experience. ²If the employee has a relevant work experience of at least a year, they are hired at Level 2; if they have a relevant work experience of at least three years, they are assigned Level 3. ³Irrespective of this, for purposes of finding personnel, the employer may completely or partially recognise times of previous work for assigning levels, if this work is beneficial for the designated employment.

So up to Level 3, there are no constraints on where you obtained your work experience.
(Note however, that experience within Germany’s public service can get you hired at levels higher than three as per §16(2), 3 or § 16(3).)

However, there is a large wiggle room as to what counts as a relevant work experience. This is where [Lighthouse Keeper’s answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/201934/7734) comes in: You have to convince some bureaucrats what your previous work experience is worth. In particular, I am not surprised that they won’t count industry experience.

That being said, your situation is somewhat special: The vast majority of positions from PhD positions to staff scientists are Group 13. However, you got one of those very rare Group 14 positions. That means that you get more salary than a regular postdoc (Group 13) with the same experience. In particular, starting at Group 14, Level 2, your accumulated salary will always be higher than if you had started at Group 13, Level 3 (see below why this is a relevant comparison). On the other hand, this is a good argument for not counting typical PhD and postdoc positions, since those are not a Group 14 experience. On yet another hand, you say you have team-management experience, and team management is exactly what usually elevates Group 14 from Group 13.

Therefore I expect that arguing for Level 3 in your situation will be difficult, though not impossible.

#### Sidenote: Why some experience does count for Group 14

You may wonder why you got any experience accounted for at all (starting at Level 2 instead of Level 1) and you also report:

> I understood that their experience as a PhD student on E13 counted in E14 as a postdoc

The reason for this is that being hired into a higher group cannot be disadvantageous for you. If you had been hired in Group 13, you would very likely have started at Level 3 (the highest non-exceptional entry level as per the above). The salary of Group 14 Level 1 would be lower than that, and thus you were hired at Level 2.

The same likely applies to those PhD students you know: If they previously were employed at Group 13 Level 3 (on account of their experience during their PhD studies), they could not be hired at Group 14 Level 1, because it would have been detrimental. Thus their experience as a PhD student did count.

However, to achieve Group 14 Level 3 by the same mechanism, they would have to have reached Group 13 Level 4 as a PhD students, i.e., they would have to have worked on their PhD for six years. That’s already quite some experience and also only possible to obtain within the German system or by invoking the exception from Sentence 3 of the above law.

Comment: I couldn't understand the comparison with E13 level 3, and how I am getting more than a regular postdoc with the same experience. How is the experience considered here, that's the main question actually. I was hired especially to supervise PhD students and probably write a proposal as a continuation, so my experience must have played a role in my employment. Another thing is, I know postdocs who are recent graduates with a PhD degree from Germany, on E14, also at a better level than mine (or at least the same).

Comment: There are some places which hire postdocs regularly in E14.

Comment: @groove *Better* level, or *same* level?

Comment: @user151413 I'm not sure as I couldn't ask this directly, but I understood that their experience as a PhD student on E13 counted in E14 as a postdoc, so it's likely better than stufe 2. Even if it's the same, I have a previous postdoc even if we ignore other 10+ years of experience.

Comment: @groove Question is whether it counted *fully*. One could well argue that e.g. only the experience in the last year of the PhD is relevant.

Comment: @user151413 Okay so I should have demanded a better level I suppose. Because I also have a PhD, and additionally more, like a postdoc and some other arguably relevant experience.

Comment: @groove: See my edit as to why PhD experience may count and why it does not have the effect you think it does.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Is there a rule for "the highest non-exceptional entry level"? So if you're getting hired in public service for the first time, is your best chance level 3 in your salary group? And does it hold for every salary group (E13/14/15)?

Comment: @groove: That’s what the cited paragraph says: It describes how previous experience can get you up to Level 3 and then it stops (sentence 2). Sentence 3 is about how you can get every level if this helps finding personnel. (Don’t ask me when exactly this exception can get invoked – I have no clue.)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I thought it could extrapolate, so I asked again, sorry. Then even if they accepted my previous experience, it would be level 3 in the best case. So it's either E14 level 3 or E15 level 1 (which is the group leadership which obviously doesn't apply to me). I guess I'm not at a big loss then, just 2 years behind the best possible thing for me currently.