# Postdoc Salary in Italy compared to Germany?

Tags: postdocs, germany, salary, italy

I am applying for my first postdoc position. How do postdoc salaries in Italy compare with those in Germany? What about the average cost of living for both the countries? Particularly if I compare Trieste with Berlin/Munich

Comment: The cost of living in Italy and in Germany is highly dependent on which city you will be living in, as the rent differs considerably and will take up a substantial part of your income. Concerning the prices in supermarkets and in restaurants, they are comparable, but again, might differ from city to city.

Comment: Postdoc salaries in Italy are horrible. (Cost of living is also lower, but that's really off-topic here - you can look up cost of living comparisons between cities pretty easily. Also it's pretty easy to find German salary scales, the Italian job posting I think has to say the salary also, correct?)

Comment: But of course, the coffe in Italy is very much cheaper than in Germany and unarguable better in most places :-)

Comment: Postdoc salaries in Germany are strictly regulated: https://oeffentlicher-dienst.info/c/t/rechner/tv-l/west?id=tv-l-2023&matrix=1
Depending on how much time you spent on your PhD, you'll be classified as 13.2 or 13.3.

Comment: I want to compare between Trieste and Munich/Berlin

Comment: @Yohana The cost of living is considerably different even from Berlin (cheaper) to Munich (expensive). In Germany, you will get the same regulated salary everywhere, no matter how much the cost of living - no matter if the city is much more expensive. The same money will get you much further in Berlin than in Munich.

Comment: Not to be dismissive, but would you please seek general advice on cost of living data in both Berlin & Trieste ? It is most unlikely you will find *current* data for both of these from anyone on this forum.

Comment: Comment only since this is experience from long ago: when I was in a similar position thinking about going to Trieste (from Germany), the prof at Trieste recommended that if I consider working (in public research) for a time in Italy, better do it as early as possible since wages increase more with age/experience in Germany. Also, in Italy health insurance is bound to having residenza, i.e. an official rental contract, whereas it is bound to your employment contract in Germany (i.e., you can go for a shared flat/sublet room - in Italy back then, those usually did not have a proper contract).

Answer (score 0):

The comparison is here:

https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/compare_cities.jsp?country1=Germany&country2=Italy&city1=Munich&city2=Trieste&tracking=getDispatchComparison

However I would strongly suggest you to not consider too much the financial aspects in your PostDoc choice: it is a transient period, you should start looking for your next position from day1 of your PostDoc, so other things are very relevant, a PostDoc salary is just fine to enjoy the place you live, whether it is in Italy or in Germany or in Spain.

Good luck!

Comment: *"it is a transient period*" You mean, like this? "Ah, your're 25, completed your Master's degree and want to do a PhD now? Well, I can only pay you a 50% salary for the next 4 years, but you know - a PhD is for your qualification mainly." "Ah, you're 29 and want to start your first postdoc? Well, the salary at our university sucks compared to the cost of living, but you know - our group is great and has a fantastic network, this can only benefit you in the long run." "Ah, you're 31 and want to do your second postdoc? Well, the salary is quite low, but you know -

Comment: - this is the job from which you will apply to permanent positions, so a good working environment should certainly be more important to you right now than financial aspects." "So, you're 34 and want to have this job as a junior software developer because your academic career still hasn't worked out and you and your partner are pissed off from moving around without any finanical security? Welcome to our company, we offer you nice family benefits along the same salary as this 25 year old collegue over there who just completed their Master's degree." (Sorry for the cynic in me breaking loose.)

Comment: @JochenGlueck - although an assistant professor leaving for industry could say pretty much the same thing. I have no regrets about my pay as a grad student or a postdoc, but that was some decades ago. It certainly seems that housing, in particular, has gotten much more expensive, and salaries overall of everyone are not keeping up with that.

Comment: And, choosing slightly more net salary over a place that will position you better for a permanent position seems a poor tradeoff. On the other hand, at the national lab where I work we pay postdocs less than a staff member, but much more than a university postdoc (and often more than an assistant professor at many places).

Comment: @JonCuster While comparing salaries is straightforward (salary A > salary B), assessing a position's long-term benefit is tricky, especially as a Postdoc with more autonomy. I once chose a role thinking it was the best move, but in hindsight, it wasn't. Many of my peers progressed just as well, if not better in average universities/research labs. I'm not suggesting this is universally true, but it was my personal experience/ opinion as well as yours. Everyone's journey is unique, so what seems right for one might not be for another. It's all quite subjective.

Comment: @Yacine - indeed, how things play out is impossible to forecast with certainty. For my postdoc, the fact that it was in Amsterdam was more important than the specific salary (which was more than enough to get by).

Comment: @JochenGlueck no, I mean like "I am a PostDoc, I deserve a decent salary to live, but I will not base my choice between city A and B on the salary of a PostDoc as long as the salary is in line with the general salary situation (which is the case for PostDoc salaries, and the salary situation is crap both in Germany and Italy, btw) ". Welfare stuff are not the scope of this question (unfortunately) and are quite comparable in Germany and Italy (and Spain). 
tl,dr: one should not worry about postdoc salaries in Europe. They are in line with cost of life and there is not much to barter.

Comment: @EarlGrey I don't think it is that easy. I applied for my second postdoc position (a Top-tier university located in one of the most expensive cities in Germany) and the salary was almost the same. I realized it was impossible for a family to live with that salary and I had to reject the position. This topic is very subjective and people's situations are different. I don't think the OP asked for our opinions about what Postdoc position to choose but about the salary difference between the two countries. it is fully legitimate for the OP to make their own decision criteria whatever they are.

Comment: @Yacine I cite myself: "and the salary situation is crap both in Germany and Italy, btw". You rejected the position, as you would have rejected a similarly qualified and paid position in the same city...

Comment: @JonCuster: I don't have regrets about my PhD or postdoc salary either (and this was just a few years ago). Maybe my polemic comment hid my actual point a bit too much. I'm not saying that postdoc salaries are, in general. too low (for instance I think that they are quite reasonable in Germany). I was rather trying to say that "don't worry about the money, it's just a transient period" is a bit too easily said when the "transient period", including also the PhD, starts after several years as a student with low or no income, and can easily last until one's mid thirties.

Comment: @EarlGrey: Thanks for your kind response to my somewhat snarky comments (by the way, the downvote is not due to me). I don't think I really agree with your comment that the salary situation were crap in Germany. I find the German salary for a 100% postdoc very reasonable (at least if one doesn't lose out at the ridiculous [experience level lottery](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/201933/135841)). My point was just that the transient period you mentioned can actually take quite a long time, so I might be inclined to put a bit more weight on financial considerations than you suggested.

Comment: @JochenGlueck I know and I agree with your point of view, I start fuming when I hear someone praising the "stay hungry stay foolish" and related crap, too.
And I feel the pain of many countries simply underpaying temporary research positions (underpaid with respect to already badly paid workers... see the downfall of labor share for many western countries https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labor_share ). All this while everyone recognize that computers and IT allow even unqualified people to perform many times the tasks they were performing decades ago, while the real wages increased of some % ...

Comment: Hopefully you *don't* have to search for a new position from day 1 of your postdoc: that sucks. You should have at least some time to focus on research before having to do so.

Comment: @user151413 in an ideal world, yes, you can focus on your research, having reasonable certainty you will find a position. In the real world, no, as soon as you start a postdoc you have to look for what's coming next, unless you do your postdoc in a field or contiguous to a field where there is high demand *and* your postdoc institution is located geographically close (~100km) to where there are many companies looking for skilled people in that field. If you do quantitative finance in London, you are fine, if you do african literature in Krakow less so ...

Comment: @EarlGrey My point was more that hopefully, your contract duration is long enough so you don't have to start looking right away. There's no point to look for a new postdoc 3 years ahead.